# Principal stable $SL(2)$-bundles on a genus $2$ compact Riemann surface.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface with genus $2$. Can you give me examples of stable principal $SL(2)$-bundles on $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any irreducible flat $SU(2)$-bundle over your surface.

Edit 1: Explicitly, take two noncommuting rotations $a, b$ of order $>2$ in $SO(3)$ and lift them (arbitrarily) to elements $A, B$ in $SU(2)$, which is a 2-fold cover of $SO(3)$. Now, let $\pi$ be the fundamental group of the genus 2 surface $S$,
$$
\pi=<a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2| [a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]=1>.
$$
Let $F_2$ be the free group on two generators $x, y$. Define epimorphism $\pi\to F_2$ by sending $a_1$ to $x$, $b_1$ to $1$, $a_2$ ot $y$ and $b_2$ to $1$. 
Lastly, consider the homomorphism $F_2\to SU(2)$ sending $x$ to $A$ and $y$ to $B$. Let $h: \pi\to SU(2)$ be the composition of the above homomorphisms. 
Using the associated bundle construction, see my answer in

[Compatibility of a connection and metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516966)

we obtain a flat principal $SU(2)$-bundle over the surface $S$ with holonomy $h$.
Embedding $SU(2)$ in $G=SL(2,C)$, we obtain a holomorphic principal $G$-bundle over $S$. In order to see that this bundle is stable note that the flat $SU(2)$-bundle is irreducible (due to our choice of $A, B$); we can now apply the theorem of Narasimhan-Seshadri that the corresponding rank 2 holomorphic bundle is stable. Therefore, the corresponding principal $G$-bundle is stable as well.

Edit 2: You can find the statement and references to proofs of Narasimhan-Seshadri theorem in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimhan-Seshadri_theorem (google is your friend!). I am using above the "easy" direction of the theorem, namely that vector bundles associated with unitary representations of $\pi_1$ are semistable; they are stable provided that the unitary representation is *irreducible*, i.e., admits no proper invariant subspace. In other words, the associated flat bundle is irreducible as a flat bundle.

Comment: Could you describe explicitly it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have some questions: are $a,b$ in $SU(2)$? What is surface group? Is $F_2 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$? What type of associate bundle have I to consider? Thank's.

Comment: I added details with answers to your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why we have to take the order of $a,b$ $>2$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why we have to take the order of $a,b$ $>2$? And in you construiction of associated bundle you obtain a flat vector bundle not a principal $G$-bundle...

Comment: @ArthurStuart: These orders ensure that the flat bundle is irreducible. The associated bundle construction works the same way for every space on which $G$ acts: For instance, it can act on a vector space or on itself via left multiplication. The former gives you vector bundle, the latter gives you principal bundle.

Comment: How can I modify your construction that involves $M$ a variety and $V$ a vector space?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: Think of $V$ as anything on which $\pi_1(M)$ acts (a vector space, or a variety or a group, whatever...). Then define $\tilde E=\tilde{M}\times V$ and use the same diagonal action of $\pi=\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde E$ as I described: By covering transformations on the first factor and by the action $(\gamma,v)\mapsto \gamma\cdot v$ you have chosen on the second factor. In the case you care about, $V=SL(2,C)$ and $\pi$ acts on $V$ via $\gamma\cdot g= h(\gamma) g$, where $g\in SL(2,C)$ and $\gamma\in \pi$, and $h: \pi\to SU(2)< SL(2,C)$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Then define $E$ to be the quotient of $\tilde E$ by this action of $\pi$. The result is a $V$-bundle over $M$. In your case, $V$ is a group and you get a principal $G=SL(2,C)$-bundle.

Comment: thank you... great! The last thing: what do you mean for irreducible bundle? It depends on connection? And can you give me a reference for Narasimhan-Seshadri theorem?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: I just did.

Comment: I'm sorry... do you have some references in order to build the moduli space of principal stable $SL(2)$-bundles on a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$? In this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144470/moduli-space-of-stable-principal-g-bundles/144492?noredirect=1#comment373063_144492 that the dimention of the moduli space is $dim_\mathbb{C}(G)(g-1)$, then if $G=SL(2)$ and $g=1$, the moduli space should be $3$-dimentinal. How can I build it in pratice?

Comment: Yes, I do. I will write an answer to your other question.

Comment: Have I to posto another question or you'll anwer here?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: I just answered your other question (I assume that ste is your other login name). You may want to ask the moderators to merge the two names.